# TikZ does not use square coordinates but polar one, how to change it in order to use Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]
  \node  (v0) at (0,0) [label=right:$\emptyset$] {};
  \node (v1) at (40:-2)  [label=right:$v_1$] {};
  \node (v2) at (70:-1.6)  [label=right:$v_2$] {};
  \node (v3) at (110:-1.6)  [label=right:$v_3$] {};
  \node (v4) at (140:-2)  [label=right:$v_4$] {};
  \node (v5) at (50:-3.5)  [label=right:$v_5$] {};
  \draw  (v0)  --  (v1)
  (v0)  --  (v2)
  (v0)  --  (v3)
  (v0)  --  (v4)
  (v1)  --  (v5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here coordinates are polar. How to use square?

Comment: What do you mean? The first `(0,0)` you have for `(v0)` is in "square" coordinates (i.e. "cartesian coordinates")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The polar coordinates are `(angle:radius)`, to transform them you can use `x=radius*cosine(angle)` and `y=radius*sine(angle)`. These values you can use in cartesian coordinates, e.g. `(x,y)`